# Why does the event fire more than once?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

For the true boolean on eventListeners I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> once: A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    switch(event.code){
        case 'Digit1': 
            shoot('Ball1');
            break;

        case 'Digit2':
            shoot('Ball2');
            break;
    }
}, true);
```

In my code the function shoot is called endless. Why?

And how can I fix it? The function shoot() may start only once.

As recommended I changed 'true' into '{once: true}'. It still call shoot() endless. Do you have an idea, why?

Thanks to @CertainPerformance.

If you should have the same problem be aware, that the internet explorer doesn't know event.code.

Comment: Maybe you add the event listener more than once?

Comment: Up to now this is the only event listener in my code. If another one will be neccessary, I can't say at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter provided to `addEventListener` is *either* an `options` **object**, or `useCapture`, a boolean. Because you passed a boolean, the interpreter is considering you to have indicated that you want the function to trigger in the capturing phase, rather than the bubbling phase - which is not something you care about.

Pass an `options` object with a `once` property instead:

```
window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(event){
    switch(event.code){
      case 'Digit1': 
        shoot('Ball1');
        break;

      case 'Digit2':
        shoot('Ball2');
        break;
    }

  },
  { once: true }
);
```

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(event){
    console.log('function running');
  },
  { once: true }
);
```

Internet Explorer and other older browser versions [don't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility) the `once` option, so to support IE, you'll have to write a bit more code - manually remove the listener once it's triggered:

```js
function listener() {
  console.log('function running');
  window.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
```

Or, with the `switch` as well:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", listener);

function listener(event) {
  console.log('function running');
  window.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);

  switch (event.code) {
    case 'Digit1':
      shoot('Ball1');
      break;

    case 'Digit2':
      shoot('Ball2');
      break;
  }
}
```

Again, with more `switch` cases:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", listener); 

function listener(event) { 
  console.log('function running'); 
  window.removeEventListener("keydown", listener); 

  switch(event.code){ 
    case 'Digit1': 
      shoot('Ball1'); 
      break; 

    case 'Digit2': 
      shoot('Ball2'); 
      break; 

    case 'Digit3': 
      shoot('Ball3'); 
      break; 

    case 'Digit4': 
      shoot('Ball4'); 
      break; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tryed it without success. It doesn't work in chrome or iexplorer :-(

Comment: See snippet edited into answer, works perfectly fine for me

Comment: For non-up-to-date browsers like IE, you can't use the `once` option, you'll have to do it manually with `removeEventListener` instead. Looks like browsers implemented it around the end of 2016

Comment: I have replaced {once: true} with 'listener' function and added the function in my code. chrome still show the the endless behaviour and the iexplorer doesn't react on keydown.

Comment: I tested it in both Chrome and IE11, the listener does indeed seem to run once, and is then removed. Did you check the final live snippet in the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184074/discussion-between-newbiexxl-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 1):

The `boolean` parameter you're adding doesn't specify that the event handler should only be executing once. It relates to event capture.

To have the handler execute only once, you need to pass an options object:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { /* ... */ }, {once: true});
```